# Any connection string builder for silverlight?

Tags: c#, database, silverlight

i know of many available conenction string builder but all windows based. Is there any connection string builder that is web based? i am looking for silverlight in particular.

I should be able to create connection string to any database (database driver available on the server where website is deployed) and store the connection string and use it later to retrieve values from external systems.

Comment: Do you mean a UI? or something akin to DbConnectionStringBuilder?

Comment: i mean UI .. where i can say .. database type : oracle, authentication windows . like http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection

Comment: and i should be able to do it from silverlight web page .. i can do it from WPF or windows forms .. but i need to run silverlight as OOB to invoke those in silverlight ... but I dont want OOB as it has to be installed on the client .. i want a browser based conenction builder ..